# Using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Prove that there is no function $f$ on $\left[0,2\right]$ such that $f$ is differentiable and has continuous derivative on interval, $f(0)=-1$ and $f(2)= 4$, and $f'(x) \le 2$ for $x \in \left[0,2\right]$.

My professor suggested using the Mean Value Theorem but I am not sure where to begin or how to proceed.

Comment: If you apply the MVT for $f$ on the interval $[0,2]$ what do you get...

Comment: in this question is $f'(x)\leq 2$ for any $x\epsilon[0,2]$ or all $x\epsilon[0,2]$??

Answer (score 1):

The Mean Value Theorem states that if $g$ is a real-valued function that is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ for some $a<b.$ then there is some point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

What does the MVT tell us about your given function?

Comment: Ok so f'(c) = 5/2 > 2 so f does not exist.

Comment: That's exactly right.